# Get rest of the string to the end with mb_substr() and still set encoding

Tags: php, optional-parameters, multibyte

With `substr()` you can omit the third parameter to get the whole rest of the string:

```
substr('abcdefg', 2) // returns "cdefg"
```

You can't do the same with `mb_substr()`:

```
mb_substr('abcdefg', 2, null, 'UTF-8'); // returns empty string
```

I only found weird and ugly solutions.

- Setting a very high number as length:

  `$a = mb_substr('abcdefg', 2, 9999999999, 'UTF-8');`
- Calculating the number:

  `$a = mb_substr('abcdefg', 2, mb_strlen('abcdefg', 'UTF-8') - 2, 'UTF-8');`
- Omitting the charset parameter by using `mb_internal_encoding()`:

  `$temp = mb_internal_encoding(); // prevent action at a distance`
  `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');`
  `$a = mb_substr('abcdefg', 2);`
  `mb_internal_encoding($temp);`

Isn't there a real solution?

Comment: Not understanding why `mb_substr('abcdefg', 2, null, 'UTF-8')` does not accomplish what you want in scenarios where you are required to provide the final (encoding) optional argument.

Comment: @ficuscr, because that does not output anything: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/407e2a6c7d00f7002054a069fef3ca510061c747

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/KZ33rR

Comment: It’s working over here, maybe your version of PHP is too old? I just installed the newest (5.4), but your problem is listed on PHP.net at the [comment section 5 years](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-substr.php#77515) ago. So it seems to have been valid some day.

Comment: lesson is codepad.viper-7.com > sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com ? :)

Comment: @ficusscr. That works only for the DEV php versions. So its a bug thats solved in the new versions?

Comment: looks like it, use `-1` instead of `NULL` in older versions.

Comment: I see, it works as of 5.4.8.

Comment: -1 leaves me without the "g".

Comment: http://us.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php -> "Allow passing null as a default value to mb_substr() and mb_strcut(). Patch by Alexander Moskaliov via GitHub PR #133.".  Good question OP.

Comment: @ficuscr Good answer, make it a real one. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change log shows this as a bug fix in Version 5.4.8 (18-October-2012).

http://us.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php

> Allow passing null as a default value to mb_substr() and mb_strcut().
>   Patch by Alexander Moskaliov via GitHub PR #133.

Here is a link to the pull request thread also: https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/133

Comment: Are you sure `mb_substr('abcdefg', 2, -1, 'UTF-8');` gives you "cdefg" in PHP 5.2.17 and not "cdef"?

Comment: @AndreKR you are correct.  That reset when I re-posted the form.  I think I'll dig up my php.net credentials and try and get a warning caveat posted on that page, in the comments if no place else.  Surprised I've not been burned by this yet with all the stale PHP code I see.

Answer (score 2):

This is a difference between PHP 5.3 (and probably also in earlier versions) and PHP 5.4.

Actually, you can see the problem in the source code of PHP if you are curious.

It is the file `ext/mbstring/mbstring.c` which has the following difference in the `PHP_FUNCTION(mb_substr)` function.

In **PHP 5.3** they check for this condition:

```
if (argc < 3) {
    len = str_len;
}
```

Whereas in **PHP 5.4** they use:

```
if (argc < 3 || Z_TYPE_PP(z_len) == IS_NULL) {
    len = str_len;
}
```

You can find these definitions in the implementation of the `mb_string` function which is started by `PHP_FUNCTION(mb_substr)` in the mentioned file. Source code can be downloaded from [php.net download page](http://php.net/downloads.php).